# Pulseaudio: How do you blacklist a specific sink/output (but not source/input) from being switched to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, pulse-audio

I have a USB microphone. When plugged, the input/source is automatically switched to it, but so is the output/sink. I want to disable the latter, so that only the input/source is switched.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using: PulseAudio Volume Control

You can configure a device for only input / only output. The setting will persist even after being unplugged.

1. `sudo apt install pavucontrol`
2. Open it, click the **configuration** tab
3. Find your device and select an input-only configuration

#### For example:

[image]